# How to read an array then return it through pointer

Tags: c++, arrays

I was trying to read an input like this:

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
```

The first one is the size of an array, and the other is the array, and the output is just the read array.

But using this code, I keep getting this output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 0 1871824307 62958 7346864 0 7340368 0
```

I can't really figuring out why.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int* readArray()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int *arr = new int[n];
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    int *p= readArray();
    int *q = p;
    while(*p !=-1) 
    {
        cout<<*p<<" ";
        p = p + 1;
    }
    delete[] q;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might have gotten the impression from a poorly written tutorial or a poorly informed teacher that the position after the end of an array is automatically -1. Dispose of that notion. It's not true unless you write specific code to *put* a -1 at the end.

Comment: @OP What if one of the values happened to be `-1`?  How would you know that the `-1` means "end of array", or if the actual value that was inputted was `-1`?  And if your teacher said that `-1` is at the back of the array, no one in your class raised the question that I raised?  That's surprising, if true.

Comment: As my job was just doing the readarray() function, so I wasn't paying any attention about the main when the main() is the problem of mine. really thks for the help <3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

by writing `while(*p != -1){...; p++;}` you are incrementing `p` until the value p points to is -1. If you want to end the array with -1, you should do some changes to your code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int* readArray()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int *arr = new int[n+1]; //note here the extra 1
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    arr[n] = -1; // adding a -1 to the end of the array
    return arr;
}
int main()
{
    int *p= readArray();
    int *q = p;
    while(*p !=-1) 
    {
        cout<<*p<<" ";
        p = p + 1;
    }
    delete[] q;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this works, a better option would be to return a `std::vector` instead, which knows its own size.  The caller can then loop through the whole vector without regard to looking for any particular values. And it won't have to worry about destroying the vector when done using it, because that will be handled automatically by the compiler.

Comment: Sorry to say. The above answer is flat wrong. You should edit or better, delete it. It is misleading. You cannot use an end of array marker that is part of valid input. I am really wondering, why a wrong answer can get 5 upvotes. This somehow sheds a bad light on SO . . .

Comment: @ArminMontigny this answer is based on OP's comment where he/she said his/her job is just doing the readArray function as the case in many online coding problems (It may be a collaborative assignment too). As such this answer attempts to do so without changing anything other than readArray. (The code in the main function suggests that the array is terminated by a -1). And as the other answers and comments mentioned this code can be optimized by using std::vector and other things, but I try to explain the correct answer with as little change as possible in the asker's code.

Answer (score 1):

What Remy is talking about is this using std::vector can avoid a lot of memory access bugs that are often found in "C" style arrays.

```
#include <vector>
#include<iostream>

// for now I let the code determine the size easier to test
auto get_size()
{
    // size_t size{};       // init to 0
    // std::cin >> size;
    // std::cout << std::endl;

    size_t size = 4;
    return size;
}

// pass vector as const &
// you promise not to change content of values (const)
// and by passing as reference the vector will not be copied.
// a reference is basically a pointer that has to have a valid value
void write_values(const std::vector<int>& values)
{
    for (const auto value : values)
    {
        std::cout << value << " ";
    }
}

// using auto will help if you change types in your code later (refactoring)
// compiler will resolve this to be a std::vector<int>
auto read_values(size_t size)
{
    // vector is a good container for arrays that don't have
    // a length that can be determined at compile time
    std::vector<int> values(size);
    int n{ 0 };

    // this next line of code is a ranged based for loop
    // it will ensure that you will never go out of
    // bounds of the vector (prevents memory overwrites and bugs)
    // value needs to be a reference since you are going to change it
    for (auto& value : values)
    {
        // note you don't have to write *value for references
        value = n++;
    }

    return values;
}

int main()
{
    // make functions for small steps makes code readable
    auto size = get_size();
    auto values = read_values(size);   
    write_values(values);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer has been given and accepted.

Anyway. We are in C++.

So, we should not use raw pointers for owned memory and no new/delete. Also, C-style arrays should not be used in C++.

For the described use case, the `std::vector` is the ideal candidate and the way to go. And, in C++ algoritms can be used, to make life simpler.

Look at the following simple and short code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() {

    // Get the number of values toread and check, if input is correct
    if (size_t numberOfValuesToRead{}; std::cin >> numberOfValuesToRead) {

        // Ok, this will hold our data
        std::vector<int> data(numberOfValuesToRead);

        // Reading. No function necessary. Typical one-liner
        std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), numberOfValuesToRead, data.begin());

        // Output
        std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    }
    return 0;
}
```